# Add a Double variable representing minute into a Date in Java

Tags: java, date, double

I have a Origin-Destination matrix representing the elapsed time between 2 point in minute. I wonder what is the best way to add the elapsed time to a Date.

```
       Date clock;
       SimpleDateFormat reqDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
       clock = reqDF.parse(line[25]);
       Double distance = distDB.find_distance(O, D, mode, facility_id);
       Date current_time = clock + distance;
```

Does it makes more easier if I use a Calendar type instead of Date ?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you create your own class that exactly represents what you want.

Comment: I don't understand .?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. A Date is for `time` - what has distance got to do with time.  If you want to store the Date and Distance - then create a class with a Date field and a Double field.

Comment: If i suppose it's 2015-12-01 08:01:10.000 and i want to store the time (Date) it'll be in 7.5 minutes which will be  2015-12-01 08:08:60.000. Am I clear enough ?

Comment: Sorry I was confused by the word `distance`, anyway `7.5 minutes == 7.5 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: I changed the word `distance` to `elapsed time` in this Question to avoid the confusion over spacial vs temporal terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2016-12-23T01:23:45Z" )
       .plusNanos( Math.round( 
           yourNumberOfMinutesAsDouble * 
           TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos( 1 ) ) 
        )
```

## Avoid old date-time classes.

Actually, you should using neither `java.util.Date` nor `java.util.Calendar`. These old legacy classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

For the old classes, the [Answer by Jireugi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480789/642706) is correct. For java.time classes, read on.

## Avoid using a fractional number for elapsed time

Not a good idea using a `double` or `Double` to represent elapsed time. Firstly, that type uses [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) technology which trades away accuracy for speed of execution. So you will often have extraneous extra digits to the right of your decimal fraction.

Secondly, this is an awkward way to handle time, given that we have sixty seconds to a minute, and sixty minutes to an hour, and so on.

- In Java, use the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) or [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) classes. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html).
- In text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. So two and a half minutes would be `PT2M30S`.

## Nanoseconds

If we must work with the `Double` as a number of minutes for elapsed time, let’s convert from your fractional decimal number to a whole number (integer).

Note that the old legacy date-time classes are limited to a resolution of milliseconds while the java.time classes can go as fine as nanoseconds. So we want to convert your `Double` to a whole number of nanoseconds.

Rather than hard-code a magic number of the number of nanoseconds in a minute for this calculation, let's use the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum. That class can calculate the number of nanoseconds in a minute for us ( 60 * 1_000_000_000L ).

Finally, the [`Math.round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) function returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding to positive infinity.

```
long nanoseconds = Math.round( 
    yourNumberOfMinutesAsDouble * 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos( 1 ) 
);
```

## `Instant`

If working with date-time values in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. Each `Instant` represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant Instant.parse( "2016-12-23T01:23:45Z" )
Instant future = Instant.plusNanos( nanoseconds );
```

## `Duration`

Rather than passing around a `Double` as your elapsed time, I strongly suggest you pass around `Duration` objects.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( Math.round( yourNumberOfMinutesAsDouble * TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos( 1 ) ) );
```

You can do math with a `Duration` such as `plus` and `minus`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-12-23T01:23:45Z" )
Instant future = instant.plus( duration );
```

You can generate a String representation of the `Duration` in standard ISO 8601 format such as `PT8H6M12.345S` by merely calling `toString`. And `Duration` can parse such strings as well.

```
String output = duration.toString(); // PT8H6M12.345S
```

…or going the other direction…

```
Duration duration = Duration.parse( "PT8H6M12.345S" );
```

Comment: Thumbs up! Lets live in the new Java world using the new and better time classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this using [`Math.round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-):

```
Date clock;
SimpleDateFormat reqDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
clock = reqDF.parse(line[25]);
Double distance = distDB.find_distance(O, D, mode, facility_id);

long clockTimeMs = clock.getTime();
long distTimeInMs = Math.round(distance * 60000);
Date current_time = new Date(clockTimeMs + distTimeInMs);
```

Here the Date gets converted into a milliseconds timestamp.
Since the distance is in minutes, you need to convert it also into milliseconds by multiplying it by 60 * 1000 (= 60000) before you can add it to the start time ("clock"). Finally a new Date gets created that represents the distance from the start time.

Please find details of the Date class here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your situation, you want to get current date, then using matrix [i, j] value (which is time - in minutes) you want to update the time to give an indication of - if you start from Origin (i), till what time you would reach to Destination (j).
I would rather use java's Calendar class. it gives you more flexibility. using 'Calendar' class, you can getTime(), which returns 'Date' type instance and then use this class to add/delete your time offset (there are methods provided by this class for such manipulations) and convert the 'Date' back to Calendar.